# Are there any subtitle search engines?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering if there exist any English subtitle search engines that allow to find out what anime a certain line of dialogue was spoken in. This could greatly help identify anime, if a certain specific phrase is all you can remember.

There is currently a somewhat useful way of searching subs using Google: add `filetype:srt`, `filetype:ssa` or `filetype:ass` to the search query to only look within the files of the [according format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubStation_Alpha). But Google isn't allmighty and the results are very incomplete. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: You might want to ping @snailboat in [the Japanese Language chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language) - I'm pretty sure he's mentioned either knowing of a search engine or maybe just having a large local repository of subtitles.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to download a lot of subtitles and search through them at home.

Sites with lots of subs:

- http://kitsunekko.net/
- basically just google "anime subtitle archive" and sort by size, descending